# Can I order by IN value

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I sort by the value of an IN query?

The following defaults to "order item_id lowest first" but i actually want the sort as entered... is this possible?

e.g.

```
select item_id, item_title, item_source from items where item_id IN ('1676','1559','1672')
```

I want to return:

```
item_id     item_title    item_source
-------     ----------    -----------
1676        item_a        source_a
1559        item_f        source_f
1672        item_c        source_c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider using the `FIND_IN_SET` or `FIELD` functions to organize your results, if you already know the IDs beforehand.

```
SELECT 
    item_id,
    item_title,
    item_source
FROM items
WHERE item_id IN ('1676','1559','1672')
ORDER BY FIELD(item_id, '1676', '1559', '1672')
```

or

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(item_id, '1676,1559,1672')
```

The drawback, of course, is that you're specifying the IDs twice.  I'm thinking pretty much any reasonably performing solution will do so, though.  The only way to get around that would be to have a sort order field or something like that.

Comment: By far the cleanest solution, double hitting the ID is ok as not a heavy resource query - many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can `JOIN` these values in the `IN` predicate like so:

```
SELECT 
  i.item_id,
  i.item_title
  i.item_source
FROM items i
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT 0 sortid, 1676 id
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,        1559 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,        1672
) t ON i.item_id = t.id
ORDER BY t.sortid
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef7a0/2)

Answer (score 6):

You would need a custom `ORDER BY CASE` to apply a sort rank to each of the possible values. Obviously this becomes difficult as the size of the set increases.

```
select
  item_id, 
  item_title, 
  item_source 
from items
where item_id IN ('1676','1559','1672')
/* Custom ORDER BY applies lower order numbers to the lowest value, etc... */
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN item_id = 1676 THEN 0
    WHEN item_id = 1559 THEN 1
    WHEN item_id = 1672 THEN 2
    /* If you had others (which you don't because they're limited by the IN() clause, include an ELSE */
    ELSE 99
  END,
  /* Then complete the ORDER BY with other cols to order on as needed... */
  item_source
```

Comment: Ingenious solution! I am wondering whether there is a more generic approach though. What if you're using a result from another select statement in the IN clause?

Comment: @titusn If you're using `IN (SELECT...)` you can convert that to an `INNER JOIN` instead, and then order on a column of the joined table.

Comment: @titusn Generally, no matter how the query is constructed, if you need to fabricate a sort that isn't standard, you are going to need to use the `ORDER BY CASE` construct somewhere _for it to be deterministic_.